# Content not visible on webpage

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am creating a database website with python and django. My problem is that the content I try to get data from my class' fields doesn't appear on the id-page on django. I am able to make a successful search, and I get links for my searches. The name-field is visible in searches and on the page, but nothing else appears. When I click on the link, I go to luokka_id/number. I must be missing something but can't figure out what the problem is.

models.py

```
class luokka(models.Model):
    nimi = models.CharField('Pääkäyttöluokka', max_length=100)
    vara = models.CharField('Varakäyttöluokka', max_length=100)
    varaaja = models.CharField('Varakäyttöluokka', max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nimi
```

and on the näytä_luokka.html (show class):

```html
{% extends 'tietokanta/base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<center>
    
{{luokkalistaus}}
{{luokka}}


{{ luokka.nimi }}
{{ luokka.vara }}
{{ luokka.varaaja }}


    
</center>

{% endblock %}
```

and views.py:

```py
def näytä_luokka(request, luokka_id):
    luokkalistaus = luokka.objects.get(pk=luokka_id)
    return render(request, 'tietokanta/näytä_luokat.html', 
        {'luokkalistaus': luokkalistaus})
```

I don't get any errors to help me out here. It's just an empty page, but it should show some extra data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have named the key of context as `luokkalistaus` not <s>`luokka`</s>, so the template should be:

```html
{% extends 'tietokanta/base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<center>

{{ luokkalistaus.nimi }}
{{ luokkalistaus.vara }}
{{ luokkalistaus.varaaja }}
   
</center>

{% endblock %}
```